# position of a tab control tooltip

Tags: winapi, tabs, tabcontrol, tooltip

I created a tab control with TCS_TOOLTIPS style, hence when mouse is over tab items, it displays a tooltip which shows some information.

The tooltip always has the same x-position as the cursor and below the cursor.

I want to make the y-position of the tooltip exact at the bottom of the tab control. In this case, I need to increase the x-position of the tooltip also, in order to avoid the cursor and the tooltip overlap.

But I can not find any information to adjust the position of a tooltip of a tab control.
Is this related to `TTM_TRACKPOSITION` flag of `TOOLINFO`? When I created this tab control, I knows only : get hwnd of tooltip by sending TCM_GETTOOLTIPS message ; Treat WM_NOTIFY message and fill TTN_GETDISPINFO structure to display the tooltip. But I didn't find any information about the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-class the tooltip control and modify it's position by catching the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.